# visualizing 2D-graphs of n-dim. array via surf() in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to show 2dim. Surface plots for different combinations of 2 parameters of a 3- or higher-dimensional array in matlab. The data for the non-shown dimensions are integrated (i.e. summed in the remaining dimensions). I am using `surf()`, and for parameter combinations other than (1,2) (eg. (1,3), (2,3) ...) I have to rearrange the data matrices in order to make it work.

I am looking for an alternative command (or shorter code) which does this work.

Here's the code:

```
a=zeros(3,3,2);  
a(:,:,1) = [1 2 3 ;4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12];       % // data matrix   
a(:,:,2) = -[1 2 3 ;4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12]*2;    % // data matrix  
ai=[[1 2 3 4]' [5 6 7 0]' [8 9 0 0]'];            % // parameter vector  

mat12 = sum(a,3);  
surf(ai(1:3,2),ai(1:4,1),mat12)  

aux13 = sum(a,2);                         
for i = 1:2; mat13(:,i) = aux13(:,:,i);     
surf(ai(1:2,3),ai(1:4,1),mat13)  

aux23 = sum(a,1);  
for i = 1:2; mat23(i,:) = aux23(:,:,i);     
surf(ai(1:3,2),ai(1:2,3),mat23)
```

In other words, I am looking for a way to use `surf` for matrices `mat13` and `mat23` without the `aux13`, `aux23` variables and the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your example doesn't run because you declare `a=zeros(3,3,2);` as a matrix [3x3x2] but you immediately try to populate it as a [4x3x2] matrix, so I had to adjust your first line to: `a=zeros(4,3,2);`

If I run your code with that adjustment, your auxiliary variable and `for` loops are to reform/reshape a matrix stripped of it's singleton dimension. Matlab provide a handy function for that : [`squeeze`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html).

For example, your variable `aux13` is of dimension [4x1x2], then `mat13=squeeze(aux13);` achieve the same thing than your `for` loop. Your matrix `mat13` is now of dimension [4x2].

Since no `for` loop is needed, you can completely bypass your auxiliary variable by calling `squeeze` directly on the result of your summation: `mat13=squeeze( sum(a,2) );`

Full example, the code below does exactly the same than your code sample:

```
mat12 = sum(a,3);  
surf(ai(1:3,2),ai(1:4,1),mat12)

mat13 = squeeze( sum(a,2) ) ;
surf(ai(1:2,3),ai(1:4,1),mat13)

mat23 = squeeze( sum(a,1) ) ;
mat23 = mat23.' ;                %'// <= note the "transpose" operation here
surf(ai(1:3,2),ai(1:2,3),mat23)
```

Note that I had to transpose `mat23` to make it match the one in your example.

`sum(a,1)` is [1x3x2] => squeeze that and you obtain a [3x2] matrix but your code arrange the same values in a [2x3] matrix, so the use of the [`transpose`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html). The `transpose` operator has a shorthand notation `.'`.

I used it in the example in a separate line just to highlight it. Once understood you can simply write the full operation in one line:

```
mat23 = squeeze(sum(a,1)).' ;
```

Comment: Exactly this is what I needed.  Thanks a lot (even this word was discouraged to used in the box here ...;-)). Why do you put a point before the transpose symbol " .' " ? I thought it is not necessary.

Comment: @Futurist. Thanks for the feedback. Consider accepting the answer (the green tick mark next to the answer score) if it's what you were looking for. The real "transpose" operation shortcut is `.'`, and you are encouraged to use this. The simple `'` operator will give you the "complex conjugate" of your vector. For vectors/matrix containing only real numbers (like in your case) it look like the same operations, but if you ever have to deal with complex numbers it will mess up your results if you use the wrong operator.

Answer (score 0):

The way you write your loops isn't exactly MATLAB syntax. Below is the correct loop syntax shown.
On line 2 and 3, you are trying to load (4x3)-matrices into (3x3)-matrices. That is why you get a subscript error. You could resolve it by making the zeros-matrix bigger. Here's some Syntax fixed:

```
a=zeros(4,3,2);  
a(:,:,1) = [1 2 3 ;4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12];       % // data matrix   
a(:,:,2) = -[1 2 3 ;4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12]*2;    % // data matrix  
ai=[[1 2 3 4]' [5 6 7 0]' [8 9 0 0]'];            % // parameter vector  

mat12 = sum(a,3);  
surf(ai(1:3,2),ai(1:4,1),mat12)  

aux13 = sum(a,2);                         
for i = 1:2 mat13(:,i) = aux13(:,:,i);     
surf(ai(1:2,3),ai(1:4,1),mat13)  
end

aux23 = sum(a,1);  
for i = 1:2 mat23(i,:) = aux23(:,:,i);     
surf(ai(1:3,2),ai(1:2,3),mat23) 
end
```

Now, what are you exactly trying to do inside those loops?

Comment: Thanks, correct the first line should be as you stated; there were further two "end" statements missing, however, they should be before the last two "surf" commands, resp. Please see the answer above.